# Room db prepopulating database with hilt and persist data

Tags: android, android-room

I am prepopulating apps database with `hilt` databases `onCreate` method and everything is working good so far. I have a problem where my app does not persist updated data in database. I believe prepopulating database is happing and resetting the data or something else that I dont know of. The data stays updated as long as the app is running or in background, removing from background and starting again resets all things, much like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61161263/7291498).

I need a way to persist edited or updated data in my app and populate data only once after app installation.

table creation statement to prepopulate data:

```
CREATE TABLE words (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, en TEXT, pl TEXT, speech TEXT)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "words")
data class MyEntity (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "en") val englishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "pl") val polishWord: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "speech") val speech: String?
)
```

hilt provider:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provide(@ApplicationContext context: Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context, AppDatabase::class.java, MY_DATABASE)
    .createFromAsset("database/database.db")
    //.allowMainThreadQueries()
    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
    .build()
```

DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM words")
fun getAll(): LiveData<List<MyEntity>>

@Update
fun updateThat(ent: MyEntity)
```

Here, after using update, it shows update at that moment and as long as the app stays in background but after restart, the update is gone.

**Update**: I have found solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61442892).

Answer (score 0):

Is the database schema version in your app different to the version of your asset `database/database.db`?

You have enabled `fallbackToDestructiveMigration` which would recreate the database each time the schema changes, as defined in the docs:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder#fallbacktodestructivemigration

Comment: I am not changing schema or schema version nor I see any way the schema is changed. I am updating data only.

Comment: So the solution is to disable fallbackToDestructiveMigration